# Powerline Network Adapters dropping connection in specific cases

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

My Powerline Network Adapters are dropping my Internet connection in some specific cases.

If I use them (one is connected to my laptop, the other to the router) in some speficic usage cases, I can be sure my connection won't drop. In some other cases, the connection is dropping every 2 hours for 5 or 10 minutes.

My laptop are 8 meters to my router. The Powerline Adapters are both working Ethernet.

Cases where the connection never crashes :

```
Video and audio streaming
Video Games
```

Cases where the connection crashes :

```
Web browsing
Doing nothing with the internet connection
```

Any infos on the problem/fix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a guess but I'd think either the network adaptor on the laptop, or the power line adaptors themselves are going to sleep.

It maybe as simple as setting your laptop to max performance, or you might need to go into the driver settings on your laptop for the network adaptor to tell it never to sleep.

As for configuring the power-line adaptors, you normally have an application to configure them via, or they have a web page you can access to configure them - simply turn off any power saving options they might have.

Answer (score 0):

I have a HP Pavilion laptop running Win7 Pro. It worked fine with TP-Link powerline adapter PA9020 for several months. One day, for no apparent reason, it began dropping internet connection; connected for a few seconds then disconnected for a few seconds, then repeat.

I tried updating all network adapter drivers on the HP, but on each one I received the message "The best drivers for you device are already installed"

Tried adjusting power and screen settings; this made no difference.

During this entire time, I had excellent connection on direct cable Ethernet to router.
Also, tested TP-Link powerline adapter PA9020 using two other laptops using Win7 Home Premium; they held excellent, continuous connection with PA9020 just fine.

Finally, after trying everything I could think of, I gave up and upgraded to Win10 hoping this would resolve the issue.The upgrade did not resolve the issue; still the repeating internet connect/disconnect.

However, after I upgraded to Win10, I again went into check for network adapter updates.
When I (right) clicked update driver on "Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller", it found an update and downloaded it with "Windows has successfully updated your drivers".

That fixed it. I connected back into the TP-Link powerline adapter PA9020, it connected right up, holds a solid connection and works just fine.

I hope this helps.